# Send Xamarin Android SMS without pressing the Send button

Tags: xamarin, sms

I am new to Xamarin. I followed the example code on the Microsoft web page for the SMS send function, everything works fine except that I have to tap the "Send" button on my mobile to send the SMS. (I've allowed permission to read/write SMS already)

Is there any way I can send automatically without having to tap the Send button?

The code for SMS is listed:

```
   var message = new Xamarin.Essentials.SmsMessage(SMS_Message, new[] { Mobile_Number });
   await Sms.ComposeAsync(message);
```

Comment: You can't unless you use a external service such as Twilio or similar.

Comment: No, the **user** has to tap Send.  Otherwise your app could send millions of messages using the user's account without the user knowing.  If you want to automate sending SMS you will need to use a third party service.

Comment: That's too bad. I found that is no SMS receiving API for the Xamarin.